# displaying facebook album photos on iOS app

Tags: ios, view, image

i want to display a facebook photo album in my ios app.
i got the album and the photos graph object, i know that i can take the FBProfile picture view and set the photo id and it will do all the displaying for me.
but i have no idea how to implement my view.

it has to be set dynamically since i dont know how many pictures i will need to display until i get the albums from facebook. also if theres lots of pic i need option for scrolling. any idea how to do it? maybe sample code?
im sure many many people implemented displaying unknown number of pictures in app.
it should look similer to the home screen of the iphone where you have all your apps icon 4x5

edit: also forgot to mention that it has to be "clickable" since after they click the image i would like to send them to another view that displays the picture full size